# How do I add active class to complicated anchors for Wordpress sub-menu on manual smooth scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am new to Stack Overflow. I am using [Serlite](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1387174/serlite)'s smooth scroll code for my Wordpress site. The anchors happen to be the sub-menu items. So basically when you are on a page with anchors, it's almost like scrolling single-pager. The challenge is that I have to make sure the anchors will also work from another page. So the way that I had the anchors set up is /gallery/#architecture, /gallery/#residences, etc. So the clicking part of the smooth scroll code works. However, the onScroll(event) part is not working, namely when I scroll manually down the page, it would not identify which section it's in (the anchors are id="architecture", id="residences", etc.), and add "active" class to the a link. Right now, the code I have is:

```
function onScroll(event){
var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
$('.sub-menu li a').each(function () {
    var currLink = $(this);
    var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
    if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
        $('.sub-menu li a').removeClass("active");
        currLink.addClass("active");
    }
    else{
        currLink.removeClass("active");
    }
});
```

Do I need to try the "replace" code or something? I'm at a lost. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I have put answer that will add active class into a selected menu

Answer (score 0):

If you have child theme then open your functions.php and add below code:

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'make_class_active',10,2);

function make_class_active($classes, $item) {
    if (in_array('current-menu-item', $classes) ){
        $classes[] = 'active ';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

filter is used for change or modify existing functionality of wordpress.`nav_menu_css_class` is hook that work with css related thing while menu is load.

I haven't idea about smooth scroll effect but reference will help you:

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-a-smooth-scroll-to-top-effect-in-wordpress-using-jquery/

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately this is not working... I'm looking for when I scroll down/up the page manually, it will add "active" class to the menu item according to the section anchor the window is on. It would usually work but since my menu item link is "/gallery/#architecture", it's not recognizing the section anchor. I'm trying to figure out how to solve it by using replacing() to extract just the anchor name.